# Movie about a Wild West town which is invaded by aliens

Tags: story-identification, movie, aliens, tv

This is a movie I watched that featured a Wild West town which is invaded by aliens. The aliens resemble giant tripods from *War of the Worlds*, but they appear to be purely biological. Their weapon consists of an extremely sharp blade mounted on a tail.

The townsfolk find out that the aliens seem to consume the uranium ore that the town mines. The townsfolk then come up with a plan to kill such aliens by waiting until one such alien shows up to consume the uranium ore and then detonating it with a stick of dynamite. I think this plan ends up succeeding.

Based on my recollection, I would say it is not the 2011 movie *Cowboys & Aliens*.

Comment: Is it high plains invaders - https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1388432/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Pretty sure this is ***[High Plains Invaders](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1388432/)*** (2009).

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High_Plains_Invaders):

> *High Plains Invaders* is a 2009 American Western science fiction television film that aired on the Syfy Channel. It is the 21st film of the *Maneater Series.* The film stars James Marsters.

From [Horror News](https://horrornews.net/31584/film-review-high-plains-invaders-2009/):

> **In the early 20th century, aliens of the giant metallic insect variety invade a remote Western mining town in a mission to find enough uranium to fuel their spaceship.** Retired outlaw Sam Danville (James Marsters) leads a motley band against the menace. For the human survivors, the mystery of what these nightmarish invaders really are — and what exactly they want — is just the beginning of their problems.

The aliens in this film do somewhat resemble the Tripods from *War of the Worlds* (albeit, they're a lot smaller), and have tails with blades on them. As the synopsis above notes, they invade a remote mining town to take uranium to fuel their spaceship. In the end, the spaceship is blown up when one of the townsfolk uses a stick of dynamite to detonate a wagon loaded with uranium directly beneath it.

Comment: "...uses a stick of dynamite to detonate a wagon loaded with uranium directly beneath it."  Man, if the folks at the Manhattan project had known that was all they needed to do, it would have saved everyone a lot of trouble.

Comment: Technically that's kind of how Fat Man and Little Boy worked.  Maybe the dynamite by some incredible coincidence created a blast compression of the exact variety needed to cause implosion?

Comment: @tbrookside - well, Little Boy didn't use implosion, and Fat Man didn't use uranium. And it seems unlikely the mine was heavily enriched U-235...

Comment: @JonCuster Now that you mention it, a gun-type fission device would be even easier to create accidentally!  Wow, this is totally plausible now!

Answer (score -4):

This sounds to me like it could be [Wild Wild West (1999)](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0120891/)

Although this is more scifi than strictly aliens, but does contain a sort of large tripod based monster.

Comment: Monster? Are you referring to the giant robot spider? The OP said the aliens in the film they're looking for were _"purely biological"_.

Comment: @LogicDictates My bad, I missed that bit, it's almost certainly not Wild Wild West then if's something "purely biological"